# Compare string c and character difference

Tags: c

I have a school assignment to compares strings. 
The compare is case insensitive so uppercase or lowercase are the same. 
If the strings are equal, then the output is first string. However, if strings aren't equal, then the output is the number of different characters.
 
**Examples:**

```
Input:
    string1: LION 
    string2: lion 
Output: LION

Input: 
    string1: LION
    string2: LEON 
Output: 1 (because 'I' & 'E' is not equal)
```

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int len, c, d, i, counter=0;
    char a[1000],b[1000];
    char *temp;
    scanf("%[^\n]s", a);
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", b);
    temp = (char *) malloc(strlen(a));
    strcpy(temp,a);
    len= strlen(a);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        c= tolower(a[i]);
        d= tolower(b[i]);
        if(c!=d) counter++;
    }

    if(counter) 
    {
        printf("%d\n",counter);
    } else {
        printf("%s\n",temp);
    }
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

I already created the program but my point only 37.5/100 or i failed 5 test case from 8. So what wrong in my program?

Comment: Your program can only reliably compare 2 strings of the same lenght. If string 'a' is shorter than 'b', you will miss this fact, if reversed, you will probably crash.  So, you need to check for length of both strings. Also, i see no reason for having the 'temp' variable.

Comment: first mistake: `temp = (char *) malloc(strlen(a));` missing 1 byte

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre also worth mentioning that no need to cast the return of malloc anymore.

Comment: yes, in that case strdup would be an even better option... if temp was used...

Comment: and what about  string1: LEON String2 HUNGRYLEON what is the output then?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i use malloc to create dynamic array and temp to save first string because first string is changed to lowercase and not original from input. I already tried use static array and the program got memory limit from evaluation.

Comment: @TonyTannous if string length not same how to compare character difference, i have no idea if string length is not same

Comment: @WawoBrown no you're not changing the original strings.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ah? i think tolower is function call by reference which change the original. yes it not change the original.

Comment: @PeterJ the output is 4, where 4 come from?

Comment: @Wawo Brown ????

Comment: `s` not needed in `"%[^\n]s"`.  Should be `" %[^\n]"`.

Comment: What report should happen if the string lengths differ like "abc", "qwerty"?  Is that to be 3, 4, 6 or 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, no need to do any manipulation on strings, if the a character differ, another check to see if its because of upper or lower case is done.

Second of all, if string size range is `10-1000`, you need an extra character for the `\0` in case a string of size 1000 is tested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char str1[1001];
    char str2[1001];
    int iter = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int diff=0;
    int counter = 0;
    int len1=0;
    int len2=0;
    scanf("%s", str1);
    scanf("%s", str2);
    len1 = strlen(str1);
    len2 = strlen(str2);
    iter = (len1 > len2)?len2:len1;

    for (i=0; i<iter; i++)
    {
        if (tolower(str1[i]) != tolower(str2[i]))
        {
                counter++;   
        }
    }
    diff = (len1 > len2)?len1:len2;
    counter += diff-iter;
    printf("%d\n", counter);
}
```

---

```
Input:
    LEON
    LeON
Output: 0


Input:
    LEON
    LION
Output: 1

Input:
    LEONEE
    LION
Output: 3
```

Comment: still got 5 failed test case. maybe length of string have a impact

Comment: @WawoBrown which one ? I've edited for difference in strings size.

Comment: actually even string length is difference is still failed test case. the program success test case when i changed array char to 10000. it's strange because the question only ask (10 <= N <= 1000)

Comment: @Wawo Brown try my one :) function nr 1.

Comment: @WawoBrown can you add the strings that are failing ?

Comment: @WawoBrown try `1001` instead of `1000`. Perhaps the test is trying to compare two strings of size 1000, but then there's the `\0` at the end an extra character which might be causing the crash as `strlen` won't return good values.

Comment: @TonyTannous it's hidden. the student only have to upload and see the mark.

Comment: @WawoBrown change 
    `char str1[1000];` to 
    `char str1[1001];`

Comment: @TonyTannous yeah 1001 is worked.. it's solved i think.. yeah the null is not expected in size 1000

Comment: @PeterJ what do you mean by "zero porability" ? Perhaps it is the reason I got -1

Comment: Not mine DV ________

Comment: @PeterJ I did not say it was you :) I didn't even suspect. But it seems someone agreed with your comment and perhaps he gave a -1 because I did something wrong. So This is why I am asking.

Comment: @Tony Tannous tolower - it is safe and portable -32 is not. It micro optimization in an inefective  agorithm. https://godbolt.org/g/LW9bfr

Comment: With input `"!"` and `"A"`, the report is 0.  I'd expect 1.  The space is OK, yet unnecessary in `scanf(" %s", &str1);`.  `scanf(" %s", &str1);` is passing the address of an array.  Better to use `scanf("%s", str1);`  (no space, no &)

Comment: @PeterJ [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514834/compare-string-c-and-character-difference#comment77994124_45515122) is good.  `if (str1[i]!=str2[i]) ....` block could be replaced with `if (tolower(str1[i]) != tolower(str2[i])) counter++;`

Comment: @chux agree... I assumed only alphabet characters in input for ease of work but `tolower` is indeed simpler.

Comment: Kudos for this code calling `strlen()` only once per string.  Weak compilers don't always see that a repeated call of `strlen()` is not needed.  Your good code enforces it.

Comment: &strx in this case is OK as srtx is char[]. But if strx was an char * with memory allocated by malloc ...

Comment: Tony, @PeterJ [point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514834/compare-string-c-and-character-difference#comment77994279_45515122) is practically correct, yet the type is wrong with `&str1`, although the _value_ is almost certainly the same.  The key point is that a well enabled compiler will flag this issue.  It is better to leave the compiler well enabled and fix these pesky mis-matches, than leave the warning disabled or worse - ignore the warning.  TTFN.

Comment: Another problem - it does not display the first string if strings are considered by this algorithm equal

Answer (score 2):

Your code is hard to understand
Two version. first counts the differences and adds the difference in length. 
Second one only count differences, returns -1 if lengths are not equal
Zero returned when strings are equal

```
size_t my_strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    size_t result = abs(((int)strlen(str1) - (int)strlen(str2)));

    //or 
    //int slen1 = strlen(str1);
    //int slen2 = strlen(str2);
    //int result = slen1 > slen2 ? slen1 - slen2 : slen2 - slen1;

    while (*str1 && *str2)
    {
        if (tolower(*str1++) != tolower(*str2++))
        {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

```
int my_strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    int result = (strlen(str1) != strlen(str2)) * -1;

    if (!result)
    {
        while (*str1)
        {
            if (tolower(*str1++) != tolower(*str2++))
            {
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and in main

```
int x;
switch((x = my_strcmp(string1, string2)))
{
  case -1:
    printf("The strings have a different length\n");
    break;
  case 0:
    printf("%s\n", string1);
    break;
  default:
    printf("Number of differences %d\n", x);
    break;
}
```

Comment: it's worked if char array is 10000. i really doest know because the question need (10 <= N <= 1000)

Comment: `int result = abs((strlen(str1) - strlen(str2)));` is troublesome.  `strlen(str1) - strlen(str2)` is _always_ a non-negative as it is unsigned arithmetic.  It is interesting in that it "works" through all the `int` conversions via `abs()`.  Could leave off and use `result += strlen(s1) + strlen(s2);` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would toss in another approach that only uses 1 big buffer.

OP's approach of using `tolower()` is good.  Yet there is no need to copy the string with `malloc()` etc.  Further, there is no need to retain the 2nd line of input.

Unclear on the programming goal concerning spaces and mis-matched line lengths.  This code treats spaces like any other character by reading the line of user input with `fgets()`.  With different line length inputs, this code ignores the extra of the longer line.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void) {
  char a[1000 + 1 + 1];  // +1 for \n, +1 for \0

  // scanf("%[^\n]s", a);
  if (fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin) == NULL) {
    puts("failed to read line");
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  a[strcspn(a, "\n")] = '\0'; // trim potential trailing \n

  // now compare as code reads
  int i = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  int ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    if (a[i]) {  // If not at the end of the string
      if (tolower((unsigned char) a[i]) != tolower(ch)) { //cast useful w/negative `char`
        counter++;
      }
      i++; 
    }
  }

  if (counter) {
    printf("%d\n", counter);
  } else {
    printf("%s\n", a);
  }

  return 0;
}
```